# Why will the Home section of my navigation bar not centre properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, alignment, navigationbar

When I resize the page to see if it would work on a phone, the home section of the navigation bar won't centre properly...
It is extremely frustrating that it won't align correctly so how can I fix it? Thank you in advance if you do read and respond to this.
The site won't let me post this unless I have more details so aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"> <!-- Set character set -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <!-- Makes the website work on all devices and screen resolutions -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Roan Taylor's Portfolio</title>
</head>

<!-- Navigation bar -->
<!-- Load an icon library to show a hamburger menu (bars) on small screens -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="navbar" id="navbar">
  <li>"Strive not to be a success, but rather of value."-A.E.</li>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Projects</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  <!-- <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a> -->
</div>
<hr>
<script>
  /* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when the user clicks on the icon */
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("navbar");
    if (x.className === "navbar") {
      x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
      x.className = "navbar";
    }
  }
</script>
<style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */

.navbar {
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 1.2%;
  margin-right: 1.2%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 1.5%;
}


/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 13%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2vw;
}

.navbar li {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 45%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2vw;
  font-style: italic;
}


/* Change the color of links on hover */

.navbar a:not(.active):hover {
  color: rgb(0, 162, 200);
  transition: 0.75s;
}


/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */

.navbar a.active {
  color: rgb(51, 51, 255);
}


/* Hide the link that should open and close the navbar on small screens */

.navbar .icon {
  display: none;
}


/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the navbar (.icon) */

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .navbar a {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar li {
    float: left;
    font-size: 4vw;
    width: 75%;
  }
  .navbar a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    width: 25%;
    font-size: 8vw;
  }
}


/* The "responsive" class is added to the navbar with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the navbar look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .navbar.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .navbar.responsive a.icon {
    position: relative;
  }
  /* Why won't home centre here??? */
  .navbar.responsive a:not(.icon) {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 7vw;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
</style>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put all your list items into one container and then apply flex properties:

```
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Projects</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```